# Problems to authenticate with Google Play

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I'm trying to authenticate the users if my app with google play services. Below is a short example of my code. When i start my app, there is the pop up where i can select the e-mail address and after that, there is the pop-up with my nick and avatar.
But i still fail to authenticate.
I double checked my SHA1 fingerprints in Google Play Console and Developer Console, i tried it with a debug version and an uploaded version of my app.
Yes, i added a leaderboard and nearly everything needed.

So i tried to figure out how i did with an older app of me, where google play log in has worked and realized that it's not working anymore.

Did google do some changes from that I do not know anything?

Unity 2018.2.5
Google Pixel

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();            
Social.localUser.Authenticate(success =>
    {
        if (success)
        {
            Debug.Log("Authentication successful");
            userid = "Username: " + Social.localUser.userName +
                "\nUser ID: " + Social.localUser.id +
                "\nIsUnderage: " + Social.localUser.underage;

        }
        else
            userid = "nix";
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, google play didn't accept my tester email address for login. I used an other email address and could log in with google play.